# Controle Bootstrap 4 dropdown transform class when building Megamenu

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, megamenu

I am building a Megamenu using Bootstrap 4 `dropdown` Component.

However by Javascript it's adding CSS `transform` style item. E.g. `transform: translate3d(9px, 5px, 0px);`

It is disturbing my layout. My Megamenu markup:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu megamenu">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes.addClass('mega-menu-item'), menu_level + 1) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      {{ view_megamenu(item.url, 'first_column') }} 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     {{ view_megamenu(item.url, 'second_column') }}
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

My website has a fluid layout. I want the Megamenu always centered full-width, with a little left and right margin.

What is the best and robust way to set this up in combination with **Bootstrap 4** and **Dropdown component**?

Comment: It always help if you can provide a working example of what exactly the problem is. Can you try Bootply?

Answer (score 0):

to prevent this from happening, your "dropdown-menu" element must lie inside an element with the "navbar" class)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="navbar dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button"
    id="about-us" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
    aria-expanded="false">List</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/02tkpzby/3/)